# How popular is the light novel of Mahouka Rettousei Koukou in Japan?

Tags: the-irregular-at-magic-high-school

How popular is the light novel of Mahouka Rettousei Koukou in Japan?

All I want is the current ratings and standing of this light novel series in Japan.

Comment: We can use metrics such as sale numbers and the like, but as it stands, this question seems to be too broad or speculative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of light novels, it seems to be the best selling series of 2014. Based on sales surveyed from November 18, 2013 to November 16, 2014, it ranks #1 with an estimated 1,599,614 copies sold.

However, if you look at individual volumes, Mahouka Rettousei no Koukou volume 13 ranked #5 with 226,371 copies sold. In comparison, Kagerou Daze V -the deceiving- ranked #1 and sold 398,038.

Hope that answers your question.

Sources: [Anime News Network Top-Selling Light Novels in Japan by Series: 2014](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-01-03/top-selling-light-novels-in-japan-by-series-2014/.82853) & [Anime News Network Top-Selling Light Novels in Japan by Volume: 2014](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-01-03/top-selling-light-novels-in-japan-by-volume-2014/.82854)